# Geometry Nodes, how to randomize the height of some cubes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, random

I need to slightly randomize the heights of some cubes. (like the following image )
any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Blender 3.6+

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if all bottoms are on same height, if so, the setup is as simple as that:

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes, they are on the same height, thank u 

Answer (score 5):

In this case the node `Mesh Island` will help you.

This gives you a unique value per mesh island: *Island Index*:

[image]

You can use this value for the input *ID* of the node `Random Value`, which will give you a new unique random value per mesh island.

To ensure that only the top faces (or their points) are moved, you must also check the normals of the faces. The node `Compare` (set to *Vector* and *Dot Product*) helps you to do this.

If you compare the normals of the faces with the up-vector, and the dot product is greater than $0$, you get a selection of the corresponding points and can move them with the previously generated random value.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: thank u, I did not know about "input ID"  